# django model foreign key AttributeError

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-orm

In my Django project, I have two apps : *"music"* and *"user"*.
I am trying to create a table in my app *"music"* as a joint table between the table *"MusicPiece"* and the table *"Member"* from the other app "user". I followed what I read in other post but I got an **AttributeError** when I make my migrations :

```
AttributeError: module 'user.models' has no attribute 'Member'
```

Here are my two models.py file :
-in "music" :

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from user import models as user_models

class MusicPiece(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class MusicPieceAuthorship(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(user_models.Member,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    music_piece = models.ForeignKey(MusicPiece,
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

-in "user" :

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from music import models as music_models


class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField()
```

The weirdest thing is that when I import *music.models.MusiquePiece* in *user.models.py* it works perfectly.
And when I import *user.models.xxxx* it doesn't work in any apps.

Do you know where does the problem come from?

Comment: Search for "python circular import"

Answer (score 0):

@AlexHall is on the right track here. Try changing music.py to

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class MusicPiece(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class MusicPieceAuthorship(models.Model):
    from user.models import Member # Ugly but avoids circular imports

    user = models.ForeignKey(Member,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    music_piece = models.ForeignKey(MusicPiece,
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Also it doesn't look like you're actually using your music model in your member script so remove the line below to avoid further issues with circular imports.

```
from music import models as music_models
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I actually use music models in an other table that I didn't mention in my post. I ll try to put all the join table on the same model file so I don't have to import two times.